# Android filesearch

Tags: java, android, file, search

I am creating an app which searches for a particular file on the device.
I am using the following code.
But when i run this application it gives nullpointer exception.
I have modified the code..  the new code is as follows

```
public class Display extends ListActivity {



 List<String> fileslist;
static String searchtext;
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bd= getIntent().getExtras();
    searchtext= bd.getString("1");
    fileslist= new ArrayList<String>();
    new Display().listallfiles("/");    
    if(fileslist.isEmpty()){
    Toast.makeText(this, "YO OY", 2200).show(); 
    }
    else{
    ArrayAdapter<String> displaylist = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,fileslist);
    setListAdapter(displaylist);
    }



}

void listallfiles(String path){
    try{


    String  files;
     File  folder = new File (path);
     File [] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

     for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
     {
         if(listOfFiles[i].canRead()){
      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
      {
      files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
        if(listOfFiles[i].getName().contains(searchtext))
      fileslist.add(listOfFiles[i].getName());  


        }

     if(listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {

        listallfiles(path+"\\"+listOfFiles[i].getName().toString()+"\\");   
    }

     }
     }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 

    {
    e.printStackTrace();    

    }



    }
```

}

Stack Trace
12-13 19:35:27.072: W/System.err(513): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 19:35:27.082: W/System.err(513):  at com.mypack.filesearch.Display.listallfiles(Display.java:56)
12-13 19:35:27.082: W/System.err(513):  at com.mypack.filesearch.Display.listallfiles(Display.java:70)
12-13 19:35:27.082: W/System.err(513):  at com.mypack.filesearch.Display.onCreate(Display.java:35)
12-13 19:35:27.082: W/System.err(513):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-13 19:35:27.082: W/System.err(513):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)

This code is runnig fine.. if u wana test if for ur self.
    package com.mypack;

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main 


 {
List<String> listof;

public static void main(String [] args) 
{

 // Directory path here
  String  path = "d:\\Java\\Programs"; 
  new Main().listallfiles(path);


  }





    void listallfiles(String path){
    try{

listof= new ArrayList<String>();

    String  files;
     File  folder = new File (path);
     File [] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

     for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
     {

      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
      {
      files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
   if(listOfFiles[i].getName().contains(".class"))
    listof.add(files);


        }

          else if(listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {

        listallfiles(path+"\\"+listOfFiles[i].getName().toString()+"\\");   
    }

     }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 

    {
    e.printStackTrace();    

    }


  for(int i=0;i<listof.size();i++)
  System.out.println(listof.get(i).toString());




    }

    }
```

Comment: you never call setFileslist

Comment: fileslist is not initialized

Comment: i hav included getter and setter that is for initialization i guess.. or how can i initialize it ?

Comment: It is an object (a list, or whatever). You are supposed to create object before using them. Usually, new is the keyword, here. In your case, fileslist = new ArrayList() would be a good start.

Comment: ok i got rid of that nullpointer exception but still am getting stackoverflow error.  
12-13 19:14:05.771: E/AndroidRuntime(375): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 19:14:05.771: E/AndroidRuntime(375): java.lang.StackOverflowError
12-13 19:14:05.771: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at com.mypack.filesearch.Display.getFileslist(Display.java:85)
12-13 19:14:05.771: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at com.mypack.filesearch.Display.getFileslist(Display.java:85)
12-13 19:14:05.771: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at com.mypack.filesearch.Display.getFileslist(Display.java:85)
..

Comment: i wrote the same code in normal java program.. that was running fine.

Comment: post your modification, it seems getFilesList calls itself recursively

Comment: not possible. if your object is null, accessing it will raise an NPE. no matter the context.

Comment: filelist is empty hence everytime i get the notification

Comment: why won't you just instantiate the dang List?